# logistic regression in XLstat Vs R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, xlstat

When I do logistic regression in XLstat and do the same in R with the same data (same variables, exactly the same data ) using the following (essential) code I get totally different coefficients. Could somebody explain to me why there is such a difference and how to replicate the results of XLstat in R?

`library(caTools)
set.seed(88)
split <- sample.split(train$Recommended, SplitRatio = 0.75)
dresstrain <- subset(train, split == TRUE)
dresstest <- subset(train, split == FALSE)
model <- glm (one ~two+three+four, data = dresstrain, family = binomial)`

[image: XLStat output]

`R output
Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  -2.295e+02  8.058e+06       0        1
Altitude     -1.532e-01  1.033e+03       0        1
Pool_length  -8.374e+00  8.042e+04       0        1
Pool_breadth  1.063e+01  2.102e+05       0        1
Pool_Depth   -4.799e+02  7.066e+06       0        1
pH            8.422e+00  2.344e+05       0        1
Conductivity  3.522e-01  3.790e+04       0        1
TDS          -2.709e-01  7.375e+04       0        1
Temperature   6.800e+00  2.010e+05       0        1
Nitrate      -1.041e+03  7.301e+06       0        1
Phosphate     3.807e+00  9.269e+04       0        1
Sodium        5.410e+00  1.634e+05       0        1
Ammonium     -2.277e+02  1.696e+06       0        1
Potassium    -5.502e+01  1.133e+06       0        1
Calcium       1.969e+01  3.628e+05       0        1
Magnesium    -4.456e+01  1.221e+06       0        1
Fluride       6.257e+00  7.875e+05       0        1
Chloride      1.982e+01  6.618e+04       0        1
Bromide      -5.380e+01  5.328e+05       0        1
Sulphate      4.050e-01  3.086e+04       0        1`

Comment: Do the two resulting models include the same variables? This is relevant yet information you would want to add to the original question.

Comment: Yes. They include the same variables. The data is exactly the same.

Comment: Could you maybe add output from R?

Comment: Also add output from excel

Comment: It could be due to the random splitting (even with a `set.seed`): can you check the models are the same if you estimate them on the whole data?

Comment: The reason I am asking about variables is that it could be that there is a factor included and XLstat and R have different conventions for setting reference level.

Comment: @VincentGuillemot  R and XLstat both use logit

Comment: @StopClosingQuestionsFast I dont understand your comment about factor. Kindly explain.

Comment: Ok look at the standard errors ... huge. Your variables are doing a very poor job at explaining the dependent variable. When that is the case optimum for the underlying objective function (here the likelihood) is poorly numerically indentified if identified at all.

Comment: @StopClosingQuestionFast I forgot to mention that in r there is a warning message 'glm fit:fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred.'

Comment: Yes ok a warning is not an error. Ive seen that message before but dont know when it usually appears, maybe someone else can comment on that. Maybe also chek the variation in dependent variable ... not almost all 0 or all 1.

Comment: How large is your dataset? If your dataset does not have sufficient enough information, that could explain the warning.  Repeat the model fit using your entire dataset, do not split out a test set.  How do the results compare now?

Comment: @Dave2e There are 64 datapoints.

Answer (score 1):

> Could somebody explain to me why there is such a difference

If you have only 64 data points and estimate 20 parameters, your estimates will vary wildly, and the differences could indeed be due to different splits, or just to machine inaccuracies propagating through the fitting routine. Without your data, we can't tell.

You are overfitting badly, which is also indicated by your very large standard errors. For 64 datapoints, you can't estimate more than three or four parameters. Reduce your model *drastically*, or collect *much* more data (on the order of thousands of observations).

> and how to replicate the results of XLstat in R?

To be honest, XLSTAT [is not covering itself in glory](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/582925/1352) (see also [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/88687/1352)). I would very much question the goal of replicating its results in R, and stick with R in the first place, but that is only my personal opinion.